# Indy 10.6 IdContext needs an ID field

Tags: delphi, indy

In working with setting up TCPServer and FTPServer, the thing I noticed most is the need for a UserID field and a UserFlag field in IdContext.  The simple addition of these would greatly facilitate setting up the components for multiple clients.  You could create a descendant, but that takes a lot of unnecessary coding for something so easily added to the source code.  I modified IdContext.pas as follows:

```
Protected
  FUserFlag: Boolean;
  FUserID: Integer;
...
Public
  Property UserFlag: Boolean Read FUserFlag Write FUserFlag Default False;
  Property UserID: Integer Read FUserID Write FUserID Default -1;
```

By using these I'm able to signal a state between events and I have the reference readily available whenever an event is fired.  I tried to say something in the Indy project but I couldn't find anywhere to say it :/

Comment: Bugs and Feature Requests can be submitted to [Indy's issue tracker](http://indy.codeplex.com), or in the Embarcadero Internet/Socket forums, or just to me privately. But this feature is not one I'm inclined to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestion, but I am not inclined to make these kind of additions to the base `TIdContext` class.  They simply do not belong there.  Deriving a custom class and assigning it to the server's `ContextClass` property is the correct and appropriate solution in this situation.  This is why that property exists in the first place.  It is really not that much coding, eg:

```
type
  TMyContext = class(TIdServerContext)
  protected
    FUserFlag: Boolean;
    FUserID: Integer;
    ...
  public
    Property UserFlag: Boolean Read FUserFlag Write FUserFlag;
    Property UserID: Integer Read FUserID Write FUserID;
  end;

procedure TMyForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // must do this before activating the server...
  IdTCPServer1.ContextClass := TMyContext;
end;
```

And then you can type-cast `TIdContext` object pointers to `TMyContext` when needed.

Various Indy servers do exactly this internally.  For instance `TIdFTPServer` uses a `TIdFTPServerContext` class that has `Account` and `Username` properties for the logged in session.

That being said, if you do not want to derive a custom class, the base `TIdContext` class does already have a public `Data` property (or `DataObject` and `DataValue` properties in Delphi ARC-based compilers), which can be used for storing user-defined data, eg:

```
type
  TMyData = class
  protected
    FUserFlag: Boolean;
    FUserID: Integer;
    ...
  public
    Property UserFlag: Boolean Read FUserFlag Write FUserFlag;
    Property UserID: Integer Read FUserID Write FUserID;
  end;

procedure TMyForm.IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  AContext.Data := TMyData.Create;
  ...
end;
```

And then you can simply type-cast `AContext.Data` to `TMyData` when needed.

Comment: Thanks Remy, great suggestions :)